# Transpose large table

Tags: data, table

guys

I am sorry if this has been asked before, but I will give it a try.

I have a table (tab delimited text file) that is formatted like this

```
         Species1   Species2    Species3
 Gene 1   Value      Value       Value

 Gene 2   Value      Value       Value      

 Gene 3   Value      Value       Value      

 .
 .
 .
```

I need to change it to this format instead:

```
Gene 1   Species 1   Value

Gene 2   Species 1   Value 

Gene 3   Species 1   Value 

.
.
.

Gene 1   Species 2   Value 

Gene 2   Species 2   Value 

Gene 3   Species 2   Value 

.
.
.

etc.
```

Is there a specific unix command to do this? Or may it be done directly in Excel or something? The table has almost 120 k data points, so I think doing this manually is out of the question.

As you can probably tell, I am not exactly an expert in these things.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and incude believable input and output files (without empty lines, dots and etc) that people answering could use them for testing.

Comment: What your example data describes is not exactly what the [transpose operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) does. Please edit the title of your question or the example to clarify what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I found another solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a closer look at [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/index.html). Numpy is very powerful tool, and will help you organise your matrices any way you want it.

Take a look at the following example:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5,6]])
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
>>> a.transpose()
array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]])
```

You can also import data into numpy from a data file such as csv or txt.

```py
np.genfromtxt('path/to/myfile.csv',delimiter=',',skiprows=1)
```

As you haven't clearly described what kind of data style you are using its pretty hard to come up with what you actually need, but this should help you get started.

If you get the hang of numpy you might want to take a deeper look into [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/getting_started.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I found another solution.